# Android и MySQL

Tags: android, mysql

Умеет ли Android работать с MySQL? Если да, то скиньте где можно про это почитать, желательно с примерами. Спасибо.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: Спасибо. Недавно на мой вопрос про приложение которое будет работать с БД на сервере мне отвечали что нужно писать свое API. Можно ли считать php конструкции тут http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/ API ? Это и есть API? Просто я пока что очень далека от апи и знаю очень мало

Comment: да так и есть, в примере API написан на php.